# How do I find the parquet.writer.version from an existing parquet file?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, apache-iceberg, parquet-mr

I've started to play with Apache Parquet I was surprised about 2 versions of writers.

```
PARQUET_1_0 ("v1"),
PARQUET_2_0 ("v2");
```

Source: https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/column/ParquetProperties.java#L69

I tried to get the metadata/dump using parquet-tools to determine the version, but it did not include this info.

Currently I have a parquet file.

How do I determine the parquet write version used to write this file?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this. If you install parquet-tools you can do a :

```
parquet-tools inspect <parquet file> --detail | head -n2
```

and you get the version which is different from the format version :

```
FileMetaData
    version = 1
```

however not sure if it is impacted by the file writer version ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyarrow.parquet` to view the writer version of the Parquet file:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq    
parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile('sample.parquet')
parquet_file.metadata
```

This would print something like:

```
<pyarrow._parquet.FileMetaData object at 0x7f72447fc530>
  created_by: parquet-mr version 1.12.2 (build d35ce51f56a2166b09164cc89d7c18ce346dc83f)
  num_columns: 14
  num_rows: 11464901
  num_row_groups: 1
  format_version: 1.0
  serialized_size: 3277
```

And `format_version` is what you are looking for.

See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But I am looking for the writer version here means the data page version which is stored in the data page header and differs from format-version .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).